# como compilar aplicação em java e gerar seu Bytecodes

Tags: java, bytecode

Não consigo compilar minha aplicação a partir do prompt (cmd). Sempre que eu tento, dá algum erro. Acho que estou fazendo de forma errada porque senão já teria dado certo.

Comment: Amigo, fica difícil te ajudar se você não disse qual é a sua aplicação, nem qual é o seu erro e nem como foi que você tentou compilar, não acha?

Comment: amg so quero saber como compilar oque devo fazer abrir o cmd e fazer oque ?

Comment: @MarcosMacedo basta 1) digitar `javac` e o nome do seu código fonte, 2) apertar _enter_...  **Mas...** se não der certo, dê uma bela estudada em **[Ask]**, em **[Tour]** e em **[Help]**, e depois que entender direitinho, volte aqui e edite a questão para podermos analisar seu problema de uma maneira mais completa.

Comment: Precisa verificar também se as variáveis de ambiente estão configuradas corretamente.

Answer (score 3):

Vamos supor que você tenha o seu projeto em uma pasta `teste` e os seus arquivos `*.java` estão na pasta `src` (com várias subpastas correspondentes aos pacotes), e você queira colocar os seus arquivos `*.class` em uma pasta `build`. Além disso, há alguns `JAR`s que são bibliotecas que você quer incluir no classpath em uma pasta `lib`.

Ou seja, vamos supor que esta é a sua hierarquia de pastas é esta:

```
teste
  src
    com
      helloworld
        HelloWorld.java
  build
  lib
    biblioteca1.jar
    biblioteca2.jar
```

Primeiro, vá na raiz do seu projeto (a pasta `teste`) navegando usando o comando `cd` (ou `chdir`).

Então, no prompt digite isso:

```
dir /s /B *.java > sources.txt
javac -cp .\lib\biblioteca1.jar;.\lib\biblioteca2.jar @sources.txt -d .\build
```

Ou, se você está usando linux:

```
find -name "*.java" > sources.txt
javac -cp .\lib\biblioteca1.jar;.\lib\biblioteca2.jar @sources.txt -d .\build
```

Isso irá compilar o seu projeto e colocar tudo na pasta `build`:

```
teste
  src
    com
      helloworld
        HelloWorld.java
  build
    com
      helloworld
        HelloWorld.class
  lib
    biblioteca1.jar
    biblioteca2.jar
```

Algumas observações:

- Se você não tiver nenhum `JAR` no seu classpath, omita o `-cp .\lib\biblioteca1.jar;.\lib\biblioteca2.jar`.
- Lembre-se de usar ponto-e-vírgula para separar os `JAR`s caso haja mais que um.
- O arquivo `sources.txt` é para garantir que o compilador vai pegar todos os arquivos de código-fonte necessários, evitando que você tenha que digitá-los um a um.

Para executar o seu projeto:

```
java -cp .\lib\biblioteca1.jar;.\lib\biblioteca2.jar;.\build com.helloworld.HelloWorld
```

Ou se você não tiver nenhum arquivo `JAR` como biblioteca:

```
java -cp .\build com.helloworld.HelloWorld
```

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623161/javac-option-to-compile-recursively